# How do I add in a shortcut on the shutdown menu to a program?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file

I would like to add a shortcut to this menu here:

[image]

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

**I have Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP1 (6.1, Build 7601)**

Comment: A colleague had such a script back in the years of Windows NT so maybe you want to tell us which version of Windows you are using because I'm pretty sure that from Windows NT to Windows 8 there are different ways of doing this (I think he did some registry hacking, but it was very long time ago).

Comment: Your photobucket link is broken. Please use our own image hosting site available through the editor.

Comment: The shortcut for "the bonus question" is most likely in shell.dll... As I don't have Windows 7 I would need to research. As it is a separate question (with interest) please post it as a separate question. See this [Stack Overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162304/how-do-i-shutdown-restart-logoff-windows-via-bat-file) for the possible answer.